# Occasional invalid email when sharing file, possible issues with manual confirmation box

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having an issue with using Document.addViewer(emailAddress) on non-gmail addresses. The viewer is not successfully added and my function terminates. My issue with the former fact. The code works fine via script with many email addresses, but fails on others. I've noticed it correlates to the appearance of a dialogue box when manually sharing. Additionally, the error pop-up simply states "Invalid email: [removed]". This is the dialog box:

> You are sending an invitation to [removed]. Since there is no Google account associated with this email address, anyone holding this invitation will have access without signing in. OK CANCEL

I tried setting the permission to anyone with a link, but it still fails. I also haven't been able to find any API methods that would assist. Here is the offending portion of code:

```
// Returns URL of doc
function shareLetter(doc) {
    // Sets sharing to anyone with link
    var id = doc.getId();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);  // <-- Attempt to solve

    // Shares doc with lead presenter
    doc.addViewer(leadEmail);  // <-- Offending line here
    var url = doc.getUrl();
    return url;
}
```

Despite best practices, I am using a global variable for the email address, but I have confirmed that it works via successful runs. Hardcoding an known "invalid" email address into the addViewer(emailAddress) call still fails. Any ideas?